# visual studio code isn't noticing environment variables

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am using C and C# in vscode, but cant seem to execute them.
recently. when I tried to execute a C program, this came up:

```
gcc : The term 'gcc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:61
+ ...  "d:\codin\C_yes_they_are_different\scripts\" ; if ($?) { gcc test.c  ...
+                                                               ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gcc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException        
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

when the following command is run:

```
cd "d:\codin\C_yes_they_are_different\scripts\" ; if ($?) { gcc test.c -o test } ; if ($?) { .\test }
```

for this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf ("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

I followed this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HD0pqVtsmw&t
and I did setup the envirinment variables, yet this happens.
and I *need* help.
[environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7ZXo.png)

Comment: According to that error message you don't have `gcc` installed on your machine. What is the output you get when you run `gcc --version` in a regular command line?

Comment: well that's strange... yesterday, when I installed it and put it in PATH, it worked, but now it isnt...

Comment: Then you need to check your PATH environment variables again, perhaps something reset your changes

Comment: I have edited the post. please check the picture.
edit: thank you kind stranger of the internet! I re-added the path and it worked!

Comment: Maybe you should not put 2 different directories into one entry. That video only adds one folder.